# How to execute a DDL migration script in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Instead of using the static classes of Laravel like DB and Schema, I am trying to execute a full DDL script by reading the script then execute it towards the MySQL instance.

```
class CreateDb extends Migration {
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up() {
        $script = $this->readScript("create_tables.sql");
        DB::statement($script);
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down() {
        $script = $this->readScript("drop_table.sql");
        DB::statement($script);
    }

    /**
     * @param $str
     * @return false|string
     */
    protected function readScript($str) {
        $scripts = getcwd() . "/database/scripts/";
        $script_location = $scripts . $str;
        $myfile = fopen($script_location, "r") or die("Unable to open script file: " . $script_location);
        $script = fread($myfile, filesize($script_location));
        fclose($myfile);
        return $script;
    }
}
```

However, I am getting this error:

```
 Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'create table if not exists comments
```

When I execute the script in the console (Intellij Idea Console) it works, so I think Ii could be that `DB::statement($script)` is not the right function to do this job!

The SQL file looks something like this:

[image]

Comment: Maybe you forgot `;` at the end of each query. Do you use the same user in your IDE as the one in the application ?

Comment: @N69S as you can see from the pic I've not forgot ; I check this twice :D but a good suggestion and the user is correct, yes! The interesting part is when I execute only one create table statement it works.

Comment: Super personal recommendation (7+ years experience), do not run files or similar in migrations, that can lead to a lot of problems (if you are not tracking correctly on a VCS like GIT), write the migration as it should be and done. Do not run files.